# What I must do to get TLSv1.2 support in Google Chrome 30?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, apache-http-server, https, tls

[Here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278370#c60) one can read that Google Chrome 30 support TLSv1.2, but I can't access a server using it on Ubuntu 13.04. The server just support TLSv1.2 and have cipher `TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)` as show [this](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html) test: [image]

Opera can access the site without problem, so the server is well configured and working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome must be installed with NSS >= 3.12.1 as is in Ubuntu 13.10. See [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=278370#c63)